# How to apply Poisson noise to a deterministic function

Tags: poisson-distribution, model

Very basic question: Given a model y = f(x) , where f(x) is a deterministic function (e.g. a polynomial of order k), and x coming from a probability distribution p(x) (e.g. uniform, or normal). It is clear that gaussian noise can be added as an additive factor +n.

How can I manually apply non-additive noise such as Poisson to this model?

Comment: Your question at the end seems to imply that Poisson noise can only be non-additive. Why do you think that? Or am I just reading it wrong?

Comment: @AlvaroFuentes I assume you can always just add a Poisson distributed random variable to a signal, but that would recreate scenarios that I can' t easily imagine in real life. I am just referring to a standard modeling task of counts-data, where variance increases with the mean